# How to write the material design radio button in yii2?

Tags: yii2, material-design

I am facing issue with material design radio button using in yii2.
this is the material design radio button which is working perfectly

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="q_option" value="Recent advances in MS">
     Recent advances in MS
    </label>
</div>
```

but when I write the same radio button in yii2 framework, the radio button dot become disappear and become non clickable

```
<div class="radio">

        <?= $form->field($model, 'q_option')->radio(
          ['label' => 'Recent advances in MS', 'value' => 'Recent advances in MS']
        ) ?>

</div>
```

please guide me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe be you mean radio buttons? Single radio doesnt have mean.

```
//controller
$model = new Cities();
        return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);

//view <?php
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
<div class="radio">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'city_name')->radio(
          ['label' => 'Recent advances in MS', 'value' => 'Recent advances in MS']
        ) ?>
</div>
<?php $form::end() ?>
```

work well

You use $model and table_field_name. Maybe you tried use radio button list? Like that:

```
//view 
$model = new Cities();
        return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $model,
            'array' => Cities::find()->all(),
        ]);

//controller
<?php
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'city_name')
    ->radioList(ArrayHelper::map($array, 'id', 'city_name')) ?>
<?php $form::end() ?>
```